# How to make httpc request and attach client certificate?

Tags: erlang

I have an IIS hosted site that requires a client certificate to be attached to any incoming requests. I am trying to make a request from Erlang and am having trouble figuring out how to attach a client to the outgoing httpc request.  My sample code:

```
inets:start(),
ssl:start(),
httpc:request(get, {"https://my-iis-host.org/api/endpoint?parm1=foobar", []}, [{ssl, [{cacertfile, "/path/to/my/cert.pem"}]}], []) .
```

returns a 403.7 response from the server.  I'm sure the cert is good because I can use `curl` and successfully make the same call and get a successful response:

`curl -v --cert /path/to/my/cert.pem "https://my-iis-host.org/api/endpoint?parm1=foobar"`

I assume my erlang call is wrong and its not actually attaching the client certificate to the request, but how is it supposed to work?  Thanks for any help!

Edit: Ultimately the problem I was trying to solve was actually to `POST` data to an endpoint and attach a client certificate.  I reproduced it with `GET` for simplicity, but wanted to share my full `POST` example that ended up working in case others run into the same question:

```
inets:start(),
ssl:start(),
Body = "{'name':'value','name1':'value1'}",
Request = {"https://my-iis-host.org/api/endpoint", [], "application/json", Body},
httpc:request(post, Request, [{ssl, [{certfile, "/path/to/my/cert.pem"}]}], []) .
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the `--cacert` option for your curl request?  *I assume my erlang call is wrong and its not actually attaching the client certificate to the request,* -- How would you find out for sure?

Comment: Those are fair questions. For `curl`, I know the `--cert` attaches the client certificate. As far as I can tell in the erlang docs (https://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#type-client_cafile) `cacertfile` was the closest that seemed to be similar. But it's probably wrong in that it's not working for me. And I don't know for sure that the client cert is not being attached, other than the 407.3 response I get, and that the cert works successfully with curl. Do you know the correct way to attach a client cert to a request in erlang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `certfile` option instead of `cacertfile`. Try

```
httpc:request(get, {"https://my-iis-host.org/api/endpoint?parm1=foobar", []}, [{ssl, [{certfile, "/path/to/my/cert.pem"}]}], []).`
```

Comment: Thanks!  This simple example got me on my way!

Answer (score 1):

`curl` has these options available:

```
--cert
--cacert
```

You chose to use the `--cert` option, and your curl request succeeded.

erlang lists the following choices for [ssloption()](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-6.3/lib/ssl-5.3.8/doc/html/ssl.html):

> ssloption() = {verify, verify_type()} | {verify_fun, {fun(), term()}}
> | {fail_if_no_peer_cert, boolean()} {depth, integer()} | {cert,
> der_encoded()}| **{certfile, path()}** | {key, {'RSAPrivateKey'|
> 'DSAPrivateKey' | 'ECPrivateKey' |'PrivateKeyInfo', der_encoded()}} |
> {keyfile, path()} | {password, string()} | {cacerts, [der_encoded()]}
> | **{cacertfile, path()}** | |{dh, der_encoded()} | {dhfile, path()} |
> {ciphers, ciphers()} | {user_lookup_fun, {fun(), term()}},
> {psk_identity, string()}, {srp_identity, {string(), string()}} |
> {ssl_imp, ssl_imp()} | {reuse_sessions, boolean()} | {reuse_session,
> fun()} {next_protocols_advertised, [binary()]} |
> {client_preferred_next_protocols, {client | server, [binary()]} |
> {client | server, [binary()], binary()}} | {log_alert, boolean()} |
> {server_name_indication, hostname() | disable}

To be consistent with your curl request, one would think you would have chosen `{certfile, path()}`.

Comment: Thanks, `certfile` did seem to be part of the culprit. One would think that the documentation might be more clear when searching for "client certificate" in it, or that it might provide concrete examples of usage, too....I'm new to erlang, but the man pages leave some to be desired, IMHO...

Comment: @PeterTirrell, *`certfile` did seem to be part of the culprit*---Well, why don't you post what the whole culprit was?